# Deploying docker container to production server from Visual Studio 2017 RTM

Tags: visual-studio, docker, asp.net-core, .net-core, visual-studio-2017

I'm completely lost on this.

I have installed Docker on my Windows 10 machine.  It is running.  I shared out my C drive in Settings.  I then created an ASP.NET Core 1.1 project with Docker support in Visual Studio 2017 RTM.  Once the project was created, I hit F5 to run it.  It built the container, deployed it to my local Docker installation, and launched my web browser.  There is my web site running!  Yay!

I'd now like to take that container, and deploy it to Docker running on a Linux machine, but there is no Publish option in Visual Studio for the docker-compose project.  I can Publish the web project, but only to Azure or IIS.

I have looked all over for an answer to this, but all I can find is how to deploy locally, and I've already figured that out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is currently no publish option from within the tooling that will push an image to a registry,  but you should be able to do this fairly easily.    I would recommend to build the "release" configuration of the docker-compose project which should build an image locally. You can then use the docker command line to push that image to Docker Hub or Azure Container Registry,  in which you can then pull it down to the Linux docker machine.

Comment: I see.  Command line it is.  I imagine there's a way to do it without pushing to the cloud?

Comment: @TheCodeFiend  Is there any way to publish image file locally without including cloud?

Comment: @AHMADSUMRAIZ Not an easy way that I've found.  I abandoned the idea of using Docker for that project a while back because of it.  It now looks like solutions like Kubernetes exist to manage docker containers.  I haven't looked much into it yet, so I can't help you there.

Answer (score 0):

If your code is stored in a Git repo and it has a Dockerfile in the root, you can use [Cycle](https://cycle.io) to build the image on the server and deploy it there all in one easy to use interface.